# showdialog causes an unwanted behaviour

Tags: c#

I have in my application a form which by clicking on a help button it opens a help form using the function show(). when I open another dialog from the same main form with showDialog() teh help form is disabled . Do you have any Idea ? I don't want to  open the dialog with show()....

Answer (score 8):

The whole point of `ShowDialog` is that it opens it in a *modal* way, i.e. it blocks the existing forms. If you don't want that behaviour, don't use `ShowDialog`. Why don't you want to use the non-modal `Show` method?

EDIT: If you only want to effectively "disable" a single form, I *suspect* you'll need to run that form on a different UI thread. I *think* that a modal dialog affects all other forms on the same UI thread as the one which called `ShowDialog`. (The `ShowDialog` call blocks that UI thread, after all.)

Comment: Indeed ShowDialog blocks the UI thread (which meens every form)

Comment: @Zenuka: It doesn't *have* to mean every form - you can run multiple UI threads.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to achieve what you want is to open your second dialog using the overload of Show that accepts the main form as the owner parameter, and disable the main form at the same time, like this:

```
frmDialog myDialog = new frmDialog();
frmDialog.Show(this);
this.Enabled = false;
```

Then, in the FormClosing event of the dialog form (frmDialog), you re-enable the main form like this:

```
this.Owner.Enabled = true;
```

This will make the dialog act as if it's been opened with ShowDialog(), while still leaving your help form enabled and accessible.